# MSI - WiX CustomAction

Tags: c#, combobox, wix, wix3.7

I have a custom action that shows list of application pools in the system and want to bind these values into combobox which is inside customdlg.wxs and while executing  MSI setup I should get a combobox that show list of app pools.

Can anyone guide me how to bind values to combobox?

custom action

```
//List all App pools    
public static ActionResult GetAppPools(Session session)
{
    using (ServerManager iisMgr=new ServerManager())
    {
        System.Collections.IEnumerator ie = iisMgr.ApplicationPools.GetEnumerator();
        List<string> apppools = new List<string>();

        while (ie.MoveNext())
        {
            apppools.Add(((Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool)(ie.Current)).Name);
        }
    }
    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

customdlg.wxs

```
<Control Id="ApplicationPoolLabel" Type="Text" Y="94" X="11" Width="349"  Height="16" TabSkip="no" Text="Application Pool: " />
<Control Id="ApplicationPoolCombo" Type="ComboBox" Y="94" X="100" Width="150" Height="16" ToolTip="Application Pool" Property="APP_POOL" Text="{80}">
    <ComboBox Property="APP_POOL">
        <ListItem Text="[APP_POOL]" Value="[APP_POOL]" />
    </ComboBox>
</Control>
```

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/web-application-installer-in-wix

Comment: @Morten: Any reason to not coin your comment into an answer? This would allow the OP to set this question to "answered".